# sorting list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, prefix

if I have a list of strings e.g. `["a143.txt", "a9.txt", ]` how can I sort it in ascending order by the numbers in the list, rather than by the string.  I.e. I want `"a9.txt"` to appear before `"a143.txt"` since `9 < 143`.

thanks.

Comment: This question does not appear to have anything to do with `scipy` or `numpy`. If this is the case, please remove those tags.

Comment: Edited tags. Now it's more clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you sort files numerically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623446/how-do-you-sort-files-numerically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python analog of natsort function (sort a list using a "natural order" algorithm)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545532/python-analog-of-natsort-function-sort-a-list-using-a-natural-order-algorithm)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's called "natural sort order", 
From http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html

Try this:

```
import re 

def sort_nicely( l ): 
  """ Sort the given list in the way that humans expect. 
  """ 
  convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text 
  alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ] 
  l.sort( key=alphanum_key )
```

Comment: I'd use `text.lower()` at the end of the `convert = ` line to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: +1.  You might want to replace the lambda with a proper function definition, for readability.  Incidentally, Debian package version numbers are compared more or less like this.  http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version

Comment: +1 Nice answer. The only thing I didin't like are extra white-spaces. I mean here: `[ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ]` and `l.sort( key=alphanum_key )` and `sort_nicely( l )`

Comment: +1, nicely done! I redid alphanum_key as `alphanum_key = lambda key: map(convert, re.split('([0-9]+)', key))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `list.sort()` and provide your own function for the `key` argument. Your function will be called for each item in the list (and passed the item), and is expected to return a version of that item that will be sorted.

See http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely disregard the strings, then you should do

```
import re
numre = re.compile('[0-9]+')
def extractNum(s):
    return int(numre.search(s).group())

myList = ["a143.txt", "a9.txt", ]
myList.sort(key=extractNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

`list.sort()` is deprecated (see [Python.org How-To](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/)) . `sorted(list, key=keyfunc)` is better.

```
import re

def sortFunc(item):
  return int(re.search(r'[a-zA-Z](\d+)', item).group(1))

myList = ["a143.txt", "a9.txt"]

print sorted(myList, key=sortFunc)
```

Comment: list.sort() is deprecated? "Usually it's less convenient than sorted()" is the only thing in this direction I found. I have to say, though, that I'd be more than happy to see the in-place sorting go away, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: It is not deprecated. http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

Comment: It may not be technically depreciated but it is considered the "old" method and is labeled as such on Python.org.

Comment: True `list.sort()` is certainly slightly more memory efficient but the difference is negligible as far sensible sized lists are concerned. I can't find a good explanation for why but as far as I am aware the preferred and more 'pythonic' way of doing sorting is using `sorted()`.

Comment: It says `sorted()` returns a NEW list, not that's it's NEW. It's definitely less efficient if you really interested in modifying your list. sorted() is good for tuples.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> paths = ["a143.txt", "a9.txt"]
>>> sorted(paths, key=lambda s: int(re.search("\d+", s).group()))
['a9.txt', 'a143.txt']
```

More generic, if you want it to work also for files like: a100_32_12 (and sorting by numeric groups):

```
>>> paths = ["a143_2.txt", "a143_1.txt"]
>>> sorted(paths, key=lambda s: map(int, re.findall("\d+", s)))
['a143_1.txt', 'a143_1.txt']
```