# a way to sorting in python

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, operating-system

thank you for your interest, but i couldn't with this.

in PYTHON 3 , for example, i have a list.

```
import os
list = []
for carpeta in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
 if(os.path.isdir(carpeta)):
     LISTA.append(carpeta)
print(LISTA)
~
$THIS IT PRINTS JUST THE DIRECTORIES:
['1. Introducción', '10. Área de Texto', '11. Listas de Selección', '12. Estructura de Archivo HTML', '13. Estructura del Proyecto', '14. Incluir CSS', '15. Selecciones con CSS', '16. reset.css', '17. Box Model', '18. Elementos flotantes', '19. Anchos Máximos y Mínimos', '2. Conceptos Básicos de Desarrollo Web', '20. Centrado Horizontal', '21. Imagen de Fondo', '22. Fuentes con Formato', '23. Formateando Listas', '24. Formateando Tablas', '25. Resumen', '3. Títulos y Párrafos', '4. Enlaces', '5. Imágenes', '6. Listas', '7. Tablas', '8. Formularios', '9. Tipos de Input']
```

BUT , the folders, for example; have this pattern : '1. Introducción','2. Conceptos Básicos de Desarrollo Web' ...... ''9. Tipos de Input','10. Área de Texto',

it's not reading like the windows explorer

[image: sorting example that i need]

Comment: What's your problem?  That it's only listing directories, or that it's doing an alphabetical sort rather than parsing out the numbers from each directory name and sorting based on those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sort your list with a lambda:

```
sorted(Lista,key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0]))
```

`int(x.split(".")[0])` is the directory number so in `'1. Introducción'` it would be `1` and so on..

Or sort in-place `Lista.sort(Lista,key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0]))`

`sorted` creates a new list `list.sort` sorts the original list

A [link](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/sorting.html#sorting-how-to) to the docs that explains the difference between list.sort and sorted

Taken from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

`lambda_expr        ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list]: expression`

`lambda_expr_nocond ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list]: expression_nocond`

*Lambda expressions (sometimes called lambda forms) are used to create anonymous functions. The expression lambda arguments: expression yields a function object. The unnamed object behaves like a function object defined with*

```
def <lambda>(arguments):
    return expression
```

A simple example:

```
lam = lambda x : x + 4

def foo(x):
    return x+4

print("Calling foo: {}".format(foo(5)))
print("Calling lam: {}".format(lam(5)))
Calling foo: 9
Calling lam: 9
```

Comment: this was the answer more complete and works a great. 
But i dont understand good the second code. 
could you send me a link to understand please. 
THANK YOU A LOT =)

Comment: You're welcome, the lambda or the sort method?

Comment: yes, i have never seen something like that.
or what is lambda. thanks =)

Comment: I will add a link to both.

Comment: thank you =) i will be waiting

Comment: @MikeBrian, if you have any other questions feel free to ask, there is a good explanation in the docs about using keys to sort.

Comment: This will raise `ValueError` if there is no int conversion in the lambda...

Comment: @dawg what do you mean, the directory string starts with a number?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: What happens when there is a file/directory WITHOUT the number? It is an easy fix to handle that case.

Comment: @dawg Well as far as I understood all the directories are numbered but feel free to add whatever you want.

Comment: @dawg, I can add an if/else but that would not sort the list and therefore defeat the purpose, what is the alternative?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: `sorted(Lista, key=lambda field: [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in re.split(r'(\d+)', field)])` if you want a lambda or put that same bit into a key function more rationally... `def kf(field): return [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in re.split(r'(\d+)', field)]`

Comment: I was thinking `sorted(l,key = lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0]) if x.split(".")[0].isdigit() else x)`

Comment: What if there is no `"."` in the string? Don't think that a sort should sort no matter what you feed it? ;-)

Comment: @dawg if there is no number in the string neither mine nor yours will sort it ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: `if there is no number in the string neither mine nor yours will sort it` That is not true. The sort I provided A) will not raise a value error without a number; B) Will sort on the found numbers in correct sequence; C) The sorts correctly strings with NO numbers lexicographically; D) is [widely tested as the correct way](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/) to do natural sorting. Try it.

Comment: @dawg I did,  if a string happens to be missing a number then it ends up at the back of the list which is exactly what happens in my if/else.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Try with `['00001 items', '01 items', '1 item', '2 items', '9 items', '23 items', 'an item', 'item 01', 'item 1', 'item 99', 'items']` Excel, Windows Explorer, OS X, and the sort I gave you all sort in exactly that order of the list (with integers -- not float values). That is your target (ok, slight modification to the sort I gave you. Use: `sorted(Lista, key=lambda field: [(int(s), s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in re.split(r'(\d+)', field)])` so the integers with leading '0' is handled the same...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each item in your list starts with a number followed by a dot-character, you can sort your list like this (where `lst` is the original list):

```
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.split()[0][:-1]))
>>> lst
['1. Introducci\xc3\xb3n', '2. Conceptos B\xc3\xa1sicos de Desarrollo Web', '3. T\xc3\xadtulos y P\xc3\xa1rrafos', '4. Enlaces', '5. Im\xc3\xa1genes', '6. Listas', '7. Tablas', '8. Formularios', '9. Tipos de Input', '10. \xc3\x81rea de Texto', '11. Listas de Selecci\xc3\xb3n', '12. Estructura de Archivo HTML', '13. Estructura del Proyecto', '14. Incluir CSS', '15. Selecciones con CSS', '16. reset.css', '17. Box Model', '18. Elementos flotantes', '19. Anchos M\xc3\xa1ximos y M\xc3\xadnimos', '20. Centrado Horizontal', '21. Imagen de Fondo', '22. Fuentes con Formato', '23. Formateando Listas', '24. Formateando Tablas', '25. Resumen']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this snippet for sorting normally

```
def sort_nicely( l ):
    """ Sort the given list in the way that humans expect.

    Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5491962
    """
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ]
    l.sort( key=alphanum_key )
```

It changes the list itself:

```
import re

stuff = ['1.Intro','11. Look at me','2. Chapter 2']
sort_nicely(stuff)

In[12]: stuff
Out[12]: ['1.Intro', '2. Chapter 2', '11. Look at me']
```

Answer (score -1):

This is just because Windows Explorer sorts things alphabetically. If you want it to sort differently, try adding a space in front of the names you want to go first.