# Python same script opens files in order in one dir and not in another

Tags: python

for file screening I have following code in two different directories:

```
import os, re

g=open('results_1.txt', 'w') #Other has 'results_2.txt'

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename.startswith("f"):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            content =[line.rstrip() for line in f]

        A = filter(lambda x: 'KeyWord_1 :' in x, content)
        B = filter(lambda x: 'KeyWord_2 :' in x, content)

        print >> g,filename,

        for item in A:
            print >> g,item,
        for item in B:
            print >> g,item,

g.close()
```

Both directories have similar file (to be parsed my script) naming convention. So files look like this: `file_1000.txt`, `file_100.txt`, `file_101.txt`,.....,`file_1.txt`,......`file_9.txt`.

I change the script just to change the name of results file. But in one directory the files are sorted from _1 to _1000 and then results file has appropriate order while other does not. Why?

I am sorry this is related to my work and I can give any specifics.

P.S. I tried sorted function and it did not work as I wanted.

Comment: This is because `os.listdir` is unsorted. This answer might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773584/how-is-pythons-glob-glob-ordered/6773636#6773636

Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813061/nonalphanumeric-list-order-from-os-listdir-in-python

Comment: To expand on @RomanK's comment, here is the official documentation for [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) stating: *The list is in arbitrary order.*

Comment: Okay, so if I understand it right, by arbitrary we should understand it as NOT DETERMINISTIC! So difference is in one directory the arbitrary order is assumed different than the other. This can be a problem. But okay.

Comment: @algoProg: Just sort it.

Comment: Blender I will do that. In first attempt I did default sorting and it did not work. I need to do it as per the numbers in the file name. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation on `os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html?highlight=os%20listdir#os.listdir):

> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. **The list is in arbitrary order**, and does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.

You need to sort the result using a preferred sort order. You vaguely point out that the resulting order wasn't as expected when you tried sorting it, which I take to mean that you probably do not want a lexicographical sort, but a numeric sort on the trailing numbers in the filename:

```
def trailing_number(filename):
    return int(filename.split('_')[1].rstrip('.txt'))

sorted(os.listdir('.'), key=trailing_number)
```

Adapt the above to handle the real format of your filenames. Also don't forget to handle exceptions in `trailing_number` which can arise if some of your filenames don't conform to the same format.