# Delete all but latest two files matching wildcard

Tags: python, delete-file

```
import glob
import os
filelist=glob.glob("/home/test/*.txt")
for file in filelist:
  os.remove(file)
```

I'm able to delete all files through above code. But I don't want to delete latest 2 files out of 10 txt files.Rest of them wanted to be deleted.
Can someone help me please?

**Edit:**

I tried `index` to exclude last 2 files, Got different output. Files

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 test1 test 14 May 27 2015 test.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 test1 test 1857 Nov 9 2016 list.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 test1 test 140 Jun 8 22:09 check.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 test1 test 570 Jun 8 22:12 ert.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 test1 test 0 Jul 2 03:17 1.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 test1 test 0 Jul 2 03:17 2.txt
```

My new code is:

```
import glob import os 
filelist=glob.glob("/home/test/*.txt") 
for file in filelist[:-2]: 
    print file
```

**Output**

```
> /home/test/1.txt 
> /home/test/2.txt
> /home/test/list.txt  
> /home/test/ert.txt
```

Comment: Just write `for file in filelist[:-2]:` instead of `for file in filelist:`.

Comment: I think you meant *"all but latest two files matching wildcard"* so I edited your title for you to be clearer

Comment: If you know which files you want to delete then use a `sort` function and get what you desired. `date`, `time`, `size` or anything else you want. Please clarify that.

Comment: Thanks for your input.through this, i able to get output perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort your `filelist` using `os.stat(f).st_mtime` as the sorting key:

```
filelist = sorted(filelist, key=lambda f: os.stat(f).st_mtime)
```

Afterwards you iterate over filelist, excluding the last two files:

```
for f in filelist[:-2]:
    os.remove(f)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This one working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want exclude last 2 items in `glob` maches just change your `for` loop:

```
import glob
import os
filelist=glob.glob("/home/test/*.txt")
for file in filelist[:-2]:
  os.remove(file)
```

Otherwise you can use others answer to sort files and exclude last 2 files.

**Edit:**

[python 2 glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

> The `glob` module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern
>   according to the rules used by the Unix shell, although results are
>   returned in arbitrary order.

Also have a look at this:

[How is Pythons glob.glob ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773584/how-is-pythons-glob-glob-ordered)

Comment: I tried,Got different output.
Files
-rwxrwxr-x 1 test1 test   14 May 27  2015 test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 test1 test 1857 Nov  9  2016 list.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 test1 test  140 Jun  8 22:09 check.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 test1 test  570 Jun  8 22:12 ert.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 test1 test    0 Jul  2 03:17 1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 test1 test    0 Jul  2 03:17 2.txt

    import glob
    import os
    filelist=glob.glob("/home/test/*.txt")
    for file in filelist[:-2]:
        print file

/home/test/1.txt
/home/test/wars.txt
/home/test/Renewal_Certificate_RSA.txt
/home/test/2.txt

Comment: @Victory so what is the problem?

Comment: latest 2 files was included in output. I want delete all files except latest 2 files