# How to import images in numeric order?

Tags: python

I have this code to import images from a folder but the images come in the this order:

```
test1.png
test10.png
test100.png
test101.png
test102.png
test103.png
test104.png
test105.png
test106.png
test107.png
test108.png
test109.png
test11.png
test110.png
test111.png
test112.png
test113.png
test114.png
test115.png
test116.png
test117.png
test118.png
test119.png
test12.png
etc...
```

The order that I want is `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, etc...

How can I achieve that?

```
test_set = []
test_result=[]
test_dir= "C:/Users/anwer/Desktop/copy/test/"

for file in os.listdir(test_dir):
    test_set.append((give_peak_sum(test_dir+file), file))
    test_result.append((give_peak_sum(test_dir+file)))
    print(file)
```

Comment: Are all the filenames of the format `test<number>.png`?

Comment: Use `sortedList = sorted(test_result)` to sort it afterwards. Otherwise, check `glob`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6774404/1501388

Comment: yes they all are test<number>.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need to sort the list first.

If all your file starts with 'test'

you can using

```py
yourlist.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0][4:]))
```

Comment: where do I use this in the loop?

Comment: @AnwarElhadad change your `os.listdir(test_dir)` to `sorted(os.listdir(test_dir), key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0][4:]))`

Answer (score 1):

Sort by the integer in the filename:

```
import os

def key(filename):
    return int(os.path.splitext(filename)[0][4:])

files = os.listdir(test_dir)
sorted_filenames = sorted([filename for filename in files], key=key)
```

Comment: how do I implement that into my loop?

Comment: Replace `os.listdir(test_dir)` with `sorted_filenames`.