# Dynamically importing identically named classes from files in subfolder

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I need to to dynamically import identically named classes from files in a subfolder. The classes have different implementations in every file. After the import I need to create an instance of each class and store them in a data structure so I can invoke each function in thee instances.

folder structure:

```
./main.py
./players/player1.py
./players/player2.py
./players/player3.py
./players/player4.py
```

player1.py

```
class PlayerClass():
    def doStuff():
        stuff implementation 1
```

player2.py

```
class PlayerClass():
    def doStuff():
        stuff implementation 2
```

So main.py will import all PlayerClasses from these files and create once instance each to then be able to call functions like doStuff form each instance.
Something like:

```
importedClasses[0].doStuff()
```

I have managed to extract file names but I can't get the import to work from a subfolder and I can't import them as unique objects and store them in a list or similar either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach

```py
from glob import glob
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

modules = sorted(glob('players/player*.py'))

imported_classes = list(map(lambda pathname: SourceFileLoader(".", pathname).load_module().PlayerClass(), modules))

imported_classes[0].doStuff()
```

Here we are using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html) to match the pathnames to the modules we would like to import. Then import them using the [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) module ([`SourceFileLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader)).

Comment: I'm getting only the first object into the list:

```
<players.player1.PlayerShip object at 0x10e65ca90>
<players.player1.PlayerShip object at 0x10e65cf10>
```

Comment: Ah now it works! It doesn't seem ordered but that doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: The sorting in glob depends on your fs I think (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773584/how-is-pythons-glob-glob-ordered)),  but you can still sort the list with `sorted()`

Comment: update the line that sets the `modules` list as `modules = sorted(glob('players/player*.py'))` and it should be okay