# How to sort files in a folder using python?

Tags: python, sorting

How can i sort files in a folder for example `user/images/` which contains files in this order list below, objective is not to print a list of file names which is sorted but to actually rearrange files by sorting in the above mentioned folder

## Current order

```
1.jpg
5.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
2.jpg
```

## Desired order

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
```

Comment: What OS and file system are you working with, and how are you retrieving the list of file names?

Comment: Files in a directory, by themselves, have no concept of order.  It is all up to the tool that is displaying those files to the user to choose the order in which to display them.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i am using google colab

Comment: @J33T looks like [colab might preserve insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537490/image-data-is-being-stored-in-different-random-order-in-array-after-reading-from), you'll simply have to sort them as desired when enumerating them.

Answer (score 5):

Directories generally don't have an intrinsic sort order for files (or if they do, that's entirely filesystem implementation specific; as an anecdote, I had to once write a program that would copy files onto an external drive in reverse order, so a cheap MP3 player would list  them in the correct order).

That's why there is no simple, generic way to "actually rearrange files" in a folder.