# Python glob() returning list of paths in an Unexpected/Strange Pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I am using `glob()` to get the relative paths of some files in a `list`, it returns a list with all the names but in an unexpected pattern rather than in alphabetical order.
Here is just a minimal reproducible example, and it also shows the same behavior.

```
from glob import glob

default = 'database/test/gcide_'
def_paths = glob(default + '*.json')

for i in def_paths:
    print(i)
```

This is a screenshot from the directory it reads
[image]

Following is the list of paths it returns

```
database/test/gcide_w.json
database/test/gcide_n.json
database/test/gcide_x.json
database/test/gcide_q.json
database/test/gcide_a.json
database/test/gcide_v.json
database/test/gcide_c.json
database/test/gcide_d.json
database/test/gcide_o.json
database/test/gcide_r.json
database/test/gcide_j.json
database/test/gcide_s.json
database/test/gcide_z.json
database/test/gcide_k.json
database/test/gcide_b.json
database/test/gcide_u.json
database/test/gcide_f.json
database/test/gcide_e.json
database/test/gcide_p.json
database/test/gcide_g.json
database/test/gcide_h.json
database/test/gcide_i.json
database/test/gcide_l.json
database/test/gcide_m.json
database/test/gcide_y.json
database/test/gcide_t.json
```

I had recently reinstalled my OS and restored my files from a backup I had made, I doubt if that has anything to do with this problem, because prior to that it worked fine, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence of the [`glob`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) says:

> The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern according to the rules used by the Unix shell, **although results are returned in arbitrary order**.

So, there is no order to the results you get from `glob`. You can sort it in any way you want, [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6774404/83605).

Comment: But I had used this function few days back, without any sorting and it used to work totally fine. Why did the behavior change?

Comment: @DaniyalAhmad According to the documentation, "Whether or not the results are sorted depends on the file system." So it is possible that a certain setup may return sorted results.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: I now understand, as previously it was on an NTFS partition, but now is on an EXT4 partition.