# Python is not reading my .jpg/.tiff/.png file in sequence

Tags: python, glob

[You can check in the attached screenshot the .jpg file sequence is absurd, it should start from 1 to 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ8VT.jpg)

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob('images/scratch_assay/*[0-9].*'):
print(file)
```

Comment: "it should start from 1 to 10" - Why would it do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are glob.glob()'s return values ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773584/how-are-glob-globs-return-values-ordered)

Comment: As you don't have leading zeroes, you will to perform a natural sort on your list of file paths.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the returned list with `sorted(glob.glob('images/scratch_assay/*[0-9].*'))`

But consider that sorting alphabetically means that "10" will come just after "1", so the sequence will be 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

To avoid that the simplest way is probably to pad the filenames with a leading zero ("01", "02", "03", etc)