# Sort files in folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

How can I sort jpgs in a folder to 1,2,3,4 and so on?

Where do I have a mistake in my code?

```py
import os
path = "/content/drive/My Drive/output_last"
fds = sorted(os.listdir(path))
print(fds)
```

Comment: I assume you just want to print them in sorted order correct?

Comment: Yes, but they don't print in order. They print 1,10,1000,1001.Why?

Comment: Is that not in order?

Comment: No, I need 1,2,3 ......How can I do it?

Comment: This answers your question: [How do you sort files numerically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623446/how-do-you-sort-files-numerically)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, can you clarify things?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to sort numerically:

```py
import os
path = "/content/drive/My Drive/output_last"
fds = sorted(os.listdir(path), key=lambda x: int(x))
print(fds)
```

If your filenames have the `.jpg` extension, you will need sort on just the base filename. Something like this:

```
import os
path = "/content/drive/My Drive/output_last"
fds = sorted(os.listdir(path), key=lambda x: int(x.split('.jpg')[0]))
print(fds)
```

Comment: I try, but  I have error like this. invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2000.jpg'

Comment: I updated the answer to accommodate filenames with `.jpg` extensions.

Comment: Are you doing `x.split('.jpg')[0]` in order to remove the `.jpg` part to keep only the number? Aren't there more straightforward ways of doing that?

Comment: @AMC Regex but I don't know if it is faster nor more strait forward.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse If you're making the assumption that all the file names will have the `.jpg` extension, then string slicing would work just fine.

Comment: I didn't look closely at the answer. That being said split is still the better option (less hard coded), but I would split on `.` not on `.jpg`. Then you can sort by any extension provided it starts with a number. @works_as_coded

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I think once you're dealing with those kinds of nuances it's best to use specialized tools. (relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python).

Comment: @AMC As with all things computational, it really comes down to the use case. Agree that `splitext` is probably the most robust option, but the OP's description does indicate a directory with only `.jpg` files named with only digits. I also agree that string slicing accomplishes exactly the same thing in less characters of code. but you do lose the context. Six months from now I'd prefer to know what I was excising from the filename just by reading the code.